#  ActionController::RoutingError:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes

Im following the [rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users?version=3.0#code%3asample_relationships) and I've had some problems with the test but one particular error is this:

```
1) UsersController following pages when not signed in should protect 'following'
 Failure/Error: get :following, :id => 1
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches {:id=>1, :controller=>"users", :action=>"following"}
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:10:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I don't understand why It's happening if I have this on my routes.rb

```
resources :users do
   member do
     get :following, :followers
   end
end
```

and my controller is this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate, :except => [:show, :new, :create]


  def followers
     @title = "Followers"
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
     @users = @user.followers.paginate(:page => params[:page])
     render 'show_follow'
  end

  def following
     @title = "Following"
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
     @users = @user.following.paginate(:page => params[:page])
     render 'show_follow'
  end
end
```

and here is my rspec:

```
  it "should protect 'following'" do
    get :following, :id => 1
    response.should redirecto_to (new_selector_session_en_path) 
  end
```

also my routes:

```
following_user_en GET      /users/:id/following(.:format)                         {:action=>"following", :controller=>"users"}
following_user_es GET      /es/usuarios/:id/following(.:format)                   {:action=>"following", :controller=>"users"}
followers_user_en GET      /users/:id/followers(.:format)                         {:action=>"followers", :controller=>"users"}
followers_user_es GET      /es/usuarios/:id/followers(.:format)                   {:action=>"followers", :controller=>"users"}
```

Comment: before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:show, :new, :create]

Comment: thanks for reply, unfortunately thats not worked :(